# WordPress - Hide posts of other roles in backend

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, user-roles

I've two roles,

1. Members
2. Recruiter.

Both will post in Custom Post type "`Companies`".
When they about to edit/delete their own posts, I don't want them to see other posts posted by other roles. At present it is displaying title of other role's posts in the backend. Roles cannot edit/delete other role in the backend but I'm seeing other roles posts title by view link.

How do get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

> You can achieve this by using  [`parse_query`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42578641/5019802) filter with
>   `$pagenow` global variable.

1. Get the logged in user role.
2. Then get all the User ID with that role
3. Pass  those ID through `author__in` key.

Here is the code

```
add_filter('parse_query', 'wh_hideOthersRolePost');

function wh_hideOthersRolePost($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    global $current_user;

    $my_custom_post_type = 'companies'; // <-- replace it with your post_type slug
    $my_custom_role = ['members', 'recruiter']; // <-- replace it with your role slug

    //if user is not logged in or the logged in user is admin then dont do anything
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin())
        return;

    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    if(!in_array($user_role, $my_custom_role))
        return;

    $user_args = [
        'role' => $user_role,
        'fields ' => 'ID'
    ];

    //getting all the user_id with the specific role.
    $users = get_users($user_args);
    //print_r($users);

    if (!count($users)) {
        return;
    }
    $author__in = []; // <- variable to store all User ID with specific role
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $author__in[] = $user->ID;
    }

    if (is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == $my_custom_post_type){
        //retriving post from specific authors which has the above mentioned role.
        $query->query_vars['author__in'] = $author__in;
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Some what related question: [Hide "free" orders in WooCommerce orders section from admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42578641/5019802)