# Hide "free" orders in WooCommerce orders section from admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I have some events that are zero cost (free). But they are getting my orders page really full and confusing.

Now in WooCommmerce orders admin panel, I want to hide all orders which have 0 as Price.

Is there any hook or filter function available to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can remove Free order it by using [`parse_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_query) filter with
>   `$pagenow` global variable.

```
add_filter('parse_query', 'wh_alterAdminPostList');

function wh_alterAdminPostList($query)
{
    global $pagenow;
    if (is_admin() && $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order')
    {
        $query->query_vars['meta_query'] = [
            [
                'key' => '_order_total',
                'value' => 0.00,
                'compare' => '>',
                'type' => 'DECIMAL',
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: @DiegoSaavedra: thanks to you also because of this question I also get to know the versatility of `parse_query` hook. And don't forget to accept my answer as it solve your question.